# Disable image links if Retina detected

Tags: image, retina

I currently use retina.js to load Retina-optimised images on my website.

It is great, but renders redundant all thumbnail links to larger images (which load with Fancybox).

My question is how can I disable all links to images if Retina is detected? (At least until I have a higher-res camera.)

Regards

Paul

Answer (score 1):

If you want just some images on your page to be excluded from retina.js, you have to add the `data-no-retina` attribute to the tag, like this:

```html
<img src="yourImage.jpg" data-no-retina />
```

If you want to disable the links created by Fancybox, you have to modify the Fancybox source itself.